# How do I move a file into a compiled .jar file using Java?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm making a file import system, and I can't move files into the compiled .jar file the application is in.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Path FROM = Paths.get(filePath.getText());
Path TO = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + 
"\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods\\music_crafter-1.0\\src\\main\\resources\\assets\\music_crafter\\sounds\\block\\music_player");
                                       //jar file
Files.move(FROM, TO.resolve(FROM.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Why don't you just move the files into a directory and read that? In most cases the jar resembles the application along with any static data while dynamic data such as mods etc. are stored elsewhere.

Comment: Nobody does this. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the jar file internally. A Jar is *not* a directory, it is a compressed container file (pretty much a ZIP file with a different extension).

To do this, given that you are on Java 6, you have 2 options:

1. Unzip the contents to a temporary working directory (there are built
   in APIs for this, or use a library such as [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html))
   do your work (copying, deleting, etc) and then re-zip.
2. Make external command line calls to the Jar utilities that come with
   Java

Of those, only (1) makes any real sense.

A third option would be available if you could up your Java to 7+ which would be:
 3. Use a [Zip File System Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) to to treat it as a file system in code

All that said, however:

As per comments on your question, you really might want to look at if this something you need to do at all?  Why do you need to insert into existing jars?    If this is 'external' data, it would be much better in a separate resource location/container, not the application jar.

Comment: I'm using JavaSE-1.6, not 1.7.

Comment: Okay, have adjusted my answer to reflect that.  However, as a couple of other commenters have pointed out, I think you might want to take a look at if you even really want/should do this at all.