# Move files into a jar with a .bat script

Tags: batch-file

Just the title. I'm trying to make a .bat file that moves stuff into a .jar, but I have no idea what to do, or even if it's possible. If it's possible, could I be pointed towards the information that would allow me to create such a .bat file? Thanks.

Comment: See [How do I move a file into a compiled .jar file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43090674/12861751)

Comment: A .jar file is just a .zip file with a different extension. Use any zip tool that takes command line parameters like WinZip or 7-Zip, and call it from your batch file passing it the right information in the parameters to add the files. Once you pick your utility app, you can read its documentation to find out what parameters it takes and what order they should be in. (Or more easily, you could just open the file in WinZip or 7-Zip and drag and drop the files in using Windows Explorer and save the time and effort.)

Comment: This isn't my question. I want to do it using a .bat file, not Java. (HackingAddict0302)

Comment: Anyways that response solves my question, I had no idea they were exactly the same as .zip files. (Ken White)

Comment: The first paragraph of the post @HackingAddict0302 gave you says *You need to handle the jar file internally. **A Jar is not a directory, it is a compressed container file (pretty much a ZIP file with a different extension).*** Maybe when someone provides you a link in the future, you'll make an effort to actually follow it to see what it says instead of just saying *That isn't my question* based on the title. :-)

Answer (score 0):

"A .jar file is just a .zip file with a different extension. Use any zip tool that takes command line parameters like WinZip or 7-Zip, and call it from your batch file passing it the right information in the parameters to add the files. Once you pick your utility app, you can read its documentation to find out what parameters it takes and what order they should be in. (Or more easily, you could just open the file in WinZip or 7-Zip and drag and drop the files in using Windows Explorer and save the time and effort.)" - From Ken White, in a comment

Thank you Ken White, for your answer.

While I do agree not using commands is more convenient, I can't automate moving files without commands or code.
This is a valid answer. But for some reason an arbitrary restriction won't let me mark this post as the answer until two days.